# Does WordPress keep track of a post's URL history and provide automatic redirects?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I just changed the URL of one of my posts from

> http://2011.denmark.wordcamp.org/session/theme-frameworks-trends-og-standardisering/

to

> http://2011.denmark.wordcamp.org/session/wordpress-themes-mere-end-design/

Now, if I go to the old url, I get redirected to the new one. This is great of course!
...But is this a feature of WordPress, or what's going on here?

Does WP keep track of a post's URL history, providing rewrites/redirects for former URLs?
Looking at the response header I see WP is sending out a SEO friendly 301 redirect... Yes!?
I thought I'd have to set up those redirects using rewrite rules in my `.htaccess`, so I'm curious to know how it happens that WP is giving me my new URL when I type in the old one.

Any light on how WP handles this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Does WP keep track of a posts url history, providing rewrites/redirects for former urls?

Yes it does. If you change a post slug, wordpress 301 redirects the old to the new URL (if your server setup allows it).

> Any light on how WP handles this would be appreciated.

Unfortunately, I've never seen this feature properly documented in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/). Hence I cannot tell you which wp core function does this and where in the core it is located.

What I can tell you though is this: The previously used slug(s) are stored in the database in the  *wp_postmeta* table. Check for *_wp_old_slug* in the *meta_key* column (the actual slugs being stored in the *meta_value* column). Hence should you ever want this default behavior not to happen in a particular case, this is where to delete a value.

More often than not this feature is very helpful. It screws up though, when you rename a post and later on create a new post with the same name the other one had had earlier.

Comment: I found this answer helpful, and dug up a little more info on how WP does this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_for_changed_slugs/