# Removing the redirect after changing a page's slug

Tags: permalinks, redirect, slug

On one of my pages I changed the slug to form a different URL. E.g.

Old: http://example.com/old-slug

New: http://example.com/new-slug

WordPress has done it's thing of redirecting http://example.com/old-slug to http://example.com/new-slug.

I'd like to remove this behaviour as a plugin I am using makes use of the slug in question and the redirect overrides its behaviour.

I checked [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33361/does-wordpress-keep-track-of-a-posts-url-history-and-provide-automatic-redirect), and checked my `wp_postmeta` table for instances of `_wp_old_slug` but nothing is returned. My server is Nginx so shouldn't be affected by .htaccess files.

Is there anything else I can do to remove this redirect?

Comment: It seems odd that your `wp_postmeta` table *wouldn't* have any `_wp_old_slug` keys - the bit of code that does that is in `wp-includes/query.php` (wp_old_slug_redirect()) - you could add an exit or debug statement there to check if it's being called. Also, remember that if WordPress can't find a permalink, it looks posts which match the start, e.g. if you had a post called `/foobar`, then `/foo` will redirect to it.

Answer (score 7):

This (in your `functions.php`) will turn it off (but see also the comment I've left):

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'wp_old_slug_redirect');
```

It seems odd that your `wp_postmeta` table wouldn't have any `_wp_old_slug`  keys - the bit of code that does that is in `wp-includes/query.php` (wp_old_slug_redirect()) - you could add an exit or debug statement there to check if it's being called.

Also, remember that if WordPress can't find a permalink, it looks for posts with a matching beginning, e.g. if you had a post with permalink */foobar*, then */foo* will redirect to it.

Comment: Could you add your comment into the answer just to flesh it out and have all the content in one place?

Comment: Indeed, your comment was the solution. I have a page called `Events` which had the slug `events-page`. No page had the slug `events` but when visiting `example.com/events` it redirected to the `Events` page. WP was obviously matching the slug to a page with the same title as nothing else existed for it.

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me:

```
   remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

source: http://biostall.com/prevent-wordpress-redirecting-to-nearest-matching-url/

Comment: didnt work for me

Comment: Astounding that WP would have this enabled by default

Answer (score 1):

What helped for was permalinks reset. just go to `Settings -> Permalinks`, pick default, hit `Save Changes`. Then pick your structure and hit `Save Changes` again.

Comment: doesnt workkkkk

Comment: This did the trick for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To manually remove automatic redirects after slug change, just delete the corresponding rows from the "wp-redirection-items" from the database using phpMyAdmin.

This is the best and simplest way which allows you to remove redirects for specific posts. More details can be found here http://couponnexus.com/remove-wordpress-redirects-changing-slug/

Comment: How do you know the OP is using exactly that plugin?

Comment: your link doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Every WordPress post has its own slug, which is automatically generated by your post’s title. If you decide to change the post slug later, WordPress will remember the old one and redirect it to the new one. It’s possible to prevent old post slug redirection in WordPress by adding removing a couple of actions from your WordPress core with a small snippet.

Just add following code to your current theme’s **functions.php** file to prevent WordPress from redirecting old post slugs to new ones:

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_old_slug_redirect'); 
remove_action( 'post_updated',      'wp_check_for_changed_slugs', 12, 3 );
```

Comment: how does it affect SEO?

Comment: I added these lines, It doesnt work